# Hex to human readable NSString

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, hex

I have an output like:

```
63006f00 6c006f00 72000000
```

this output meaning "color" but how can obtain it in cocoa?.

I've found also this method here on Stackoverflow:

```
- (NSString *)hexToString:(NSString *)string {
NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:string];
unsigned value;
while([scanner scanHexInt:&value]) {
    [newString appendFormat:@"%c",(char)(value & 0xFF)];
}
string = [newString copy];
return string;
```

}

and it work...but my string then must be as below:

```
@"63 00 6f 00 6c 00 6f 00 72 00 00 00"
```

Any help to format the string as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code to use your original input as follows:

```
NSString *string = @"0x63006f00 0x6c006f00 0x72000000";
NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:string];
unsigned value;
while([scanner scanHexInt:&value]) {
    uint16_t a = (value >> 24) & 0xff;
    uint16_t b = (value >> 8) & 0xff;
    if (a) [newString appendFormat:@"%c", a];
    if (b) [newString appendFormat:@"%c", b];
}
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

The idea is to process two characters at a time, and shift the corresponding items into place before masking them with `0xff`.

However, this looks very much like a work-around for reading something encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: Yes it's a workaround, but it work.. with a little adjustment: NSString*string = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%@", @"63006f00 6c006f00 72000000"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"0x"]; Thank you